# Change behaviour of modifier keys

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

The danish keyboard layout is kind of stupid when it comes to programming. When I used a Macbook as my primary work laptop, I changed the layout, so a single tap of `left shift` would make an open parenthesis and `right shift` would make a closing parenthesis. In the same way `left CTRL` and `right CTRL` would make curly brackets.

How can I adopt the same keyboard behaviour in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Changing modifier keys to non-modifier keys or dead keys is hard, if possible at all. I suggest mapping a particular modifier key together with normal keys to the brackets/parentheses with `xmodmap`. The reason is that the modifier keys were not intended as dead keys, and can also be used to modify mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a utility named xcape which can do this.
https://github.com/alols/xcape

So the solution using xcape involves running the following command on startup:

```
xcape -e 'Control_L=ISO_Level3_Shift|7;Control_R=ISO_Level3_Shift|0;S‌​hift_L=Shift_L|8;Shi‌​ft_R=Shift_R|9' -t 200 on startup
```

If this is applied to a different keyboard layout, then the command needs to be different.

Comment: So the final solution I came up with using xcape was to run the command:

xcape -e 'Control_L=ISO_Level3_Shift|7;Control_R=ISO_Level3_Shift|0;Shift_L=Shift_L|8;Shift_R=Shift_R|9' -t 200

on startup. If this is applied to a different keyboard layout, then of course the command needs to be different. 

If you add the command to the answer I can mark it as accepted.